# How can I get the real client ip on dotcloud?

Tags: perl, dotcloud, dancer

I use dancer perl for my web on dotcloud. I know the problem is the setting for **nginx**. But I try my way to add the `nginx.conf` like this.

```
location / { 
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80; 
proxy_set_header Host $host; 
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
}
```

**and return 505;** 
Anyway, in my code remote_address always returns `10.*.*.*`
Can you help me with the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution:

```
my $user_ip = request->env->{'HTTP_X_REAL_IP'};
$user_ip =~ s/^::ffff:(.*)/$1/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may considered using `Plack::Middleware::ReverseProxy`.